# View All Dates/Times a File has been Modified with Linux Command

Tags: linux

Is there a linux command to view dates/times that a particular file has been modified?
I can see the last modified time and date for the file, but I need to know all of the times/dates the file has been modified in the past few weeks.
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible *a posteriori*. But see [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) (e.g. using `incron` or writing your own monitor using it....)

Comment: Thank you.  I will check out inotify.